# Numpy array, specifiyng what elements to return

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have the following 5x5 numpy array called A

```
array([[6, 7, 7, 7, 8],
       [4, 2, 5, 5, 9],
       [1, 2, 4, 7, 4],
       [0, 7, 3, 6, 8],
       [4, 9, 6, 1, 6]])
```

and this 5x5 array called F

```
array([[1,0,0,0,0],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0,0]])
```

I've been trying to use np.copyto, but I can't wrap my head around why it is not working/how it works.`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,5) into shape (2)`

Is there a easy way to get the values of only the matching integers that have a corresponding 1 in F when laid over A? e.i it would return, `6,4,1,0`

Comment: I don't know very much about numpy. Does a numpy array work the same way as a python list?

Comment: Could you post your code that you used `np.copyto` in?

Comment: I used the interpreter but basically what I did was create a random array of size n*n, made an np.array for output/destination and made a n*n array like F in my example but with dtype set as bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just do this little trick: `A[F==1]`

```
In [8]:

A[F==1]
Out[8]:
array([6, 4, 1, 0])
```

Check out [Boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html)

Comment: That's actually much better than `np.copyto`

Comment: I timed it and your solution is about 5x faster. 147 ns.

Comment: Be aware this method will always (I think) returns 1D array, hope that is what is intended. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To use `np.copyto` make sure that the destination array is np.empty.
This basically solved my problem.